# WPF Listbox Images from a database

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox, datatemplate

(How long have we been using OpenIDs? I don't seem to have one connected to any provider and no FAQ on the planet seems to tell you what to do when you lose your OpenID. I've had to create a new account. Argh!)

I'm trying to fill a (carousel) listbox from a database, but I can't get the images to display. Every single example on the net assumes you have two or three jpegs in a folder instead of in memory :(

My item class is:

```
public class PicCollection : ObservableCollection<CarouselItem>
{
    public PicCollection()
    {

    }
}
public class CarouselItem
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string ItemDesc { get; set; }
    public Image ItemImage { get; set; }

    public CarouselItem(int NewItemID, string NewItemName, string NewItemDesc, Image newItemImage)
    {
        this.ItemID = NewItemID;
        this.ItemName = NewItemName;
        this.ItemDesc = NewItemDesc;
        this.ItemImage = newItemImage;
    }
}
```

I fill a PicCollection successfully from the db(using a byte array for the image), and try to display the name and image with

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TestDataTemplate2"  >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock x:Name="CarName" 
                           Text="{Binding ItemName}"  
                           Padding="15,15"
                           Foreground="Yellow" />
            <Image Source="{Binding Source=ItemImage}"
                   Stretch="Fill" />
            </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Listbox is simply:

```
<ListBox Name="lstTest" ItemsSource="{StaticResource TestDataSource}" 
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TestDataTemplate2}"></ListBox>
```

ItemName displays ok, ItemImage does not. I've tried `{Binding ItemImage}` as well. Most examples use `{Binding Path=ItemImage}` but that's where the ItemImage would be a string containing the path, not the actual image itself.

I'm pulling my hair out. Nothing I do makes the images appear. If I create an image control and manually assign the contents of an ItemImage, however, it displays fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ItemImage property is an Image (control).  Make it an ImageSource, such as a System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.  Then you can bind `<Image Source="{Binding ItemImage}" />`.

Comment: duh! of course! That'll teach me to copy examples and paste without attempting to fully understand them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since your "ItemImage" property is already an image, you might be able to get away with just using a ContentControl to display the image directly:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Image}" />
```